# In KQL is there an 'strcat_if' function?

Tags: azure, kql, strcat, azure-sentinel

I have been working with Defender ATP, and have parsed multiple columns but due to email security I have had to parse seperated columns in the format 'potentialPhishURL' and 'potentialPhishURL_vendor', in doing so I now have two columns, where usually when the vendor has applied a shim to the URL, the standard parse fails, and so with strcat("potentialPhishURL", "potentialPhishURL_vendor") does not work as sometimes both fields are populated.

When both of these columns are populated (potentialPhishURL and potentialPhishURL_vendor) they obviously merge disgustingly and not how I need it (unique values or strcat_if empty) I guess.

Does anyone have any experience with how this is done? Merging a couple of columns in KQL when one of the columns is empty on the same row?

Thanks for reading/ helping if you can!

Comment: I think I used the wrong operator to describe best what I'm looking for, an innerunique join seems to be the best case, but so far I am confused as to whether this will join the columns only if one of them is empty, they are also in the same table so I'm not sure if join will work (as shown seperate tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `iff()` function, something like:

`iff(isempty(col2), col1, strcat(col1, col2))`

Comment: Thanks so much for this, this is pretty much exactly what I need, trouble is I am now using:
| extend allURL = iff(isempty(potentialPhishURL_vendor), potentialPhishURL, strcat(potentialPhishURL, potentialPhishURL_vendor))
This seems to strcat regardless of whether the column 2 is empty or not, column2 in this case being potentialPhishURL_vendor, as it is by far the least populated column and when merged will contain URLs parsed differently to the vendor , so now I am ending up with the vendor.com/protection/rergergrge/321342ef32/domainanalysis?=example.comexample.com if that makes sense?

Comment: So effectively the 'iff(isempty(col2' is not properly functioning in the query. Any ideas? I may be just doing this wrong, but in any case, many thanks again this is so close.

Comment: Many thanks Slavik N, I have fixed the issue despite the small issue, this was using extend cleanColumn = trim_start('.*?identifier=', (allURL))